Set up of NativeWind with className management libraries
I am working on a React Native with Expo project. I would like to set up NativeWind the same way that I normally use Tailwind. Usually, I install these libraries: clsx and tailwind-merge. Then I used them to create a function to merge styles:
import clsx, { ClassValue } from 'clsx';
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge';

export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
    return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}

Is there a way to replicate it using the native version of those libraries if there are any?

just finishing up my first project using nativewind. I'm going to say it's unlikely because native styelsheets are different to css. But really I've found that because nativewind is missing features like dynamic classes it just doesn't really bring any added value to inlining or createing stylesheet objects in a constants file. Other than a familiar workflow it didn't bring much to the project itself, an often didn't create the design outcome.

Agreed, especially if your using Expo Go on an Android.

You just need to install clsx
npm install --save clsx

Then you import it
import clsx from "clsx";

and finally you use it
className={clsx(
    "p-4 border border-white rounded-lg shadow-sm bg-elementBackground shadow-defaultText",
    extraClassName
  )}

Keep in mind it won't work if you create a prop called "className", you need a different name.
For the type of the prop, it can be a string or something like
  extraClassName?: TouchableOpacity["props"]["className"];

Sources:
https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/custom-components
https://github.com/lukeed/clsx/issues/85
